# Click off input area function using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field I want cleared. My jQuery works there but if I click the input field and then click off of it the value is back. What's the fix?

```
$('input').val('');

$('input').click( function() {
    $('input').val('');
});
```

JS fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/thomasp423/HqvmD/

It seems that normally the one line I have would work BUT I'm working with some software that probably has js overriding this and adding it back on. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Can you create an example on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: Does the fiddle you created replicate the issue you're experiencing?

Comment: No, if you read below I elaborated. There is some default js adding the value back in on the system I'm working in. I just need to override that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').click( function() {
    $(this).val('');
});
```

What you're saying is: clear all inputs when clicked on one input.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/HqvmD/1/

```
//$('input').val('');

$('input').focus( function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'search' ) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
$('input').focusout(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '' ) {
        $(this).val('search');
    }
});
```